# When you call `release` instead `destroy` on connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am asking about https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql . I am a bit puzzled what is the difference between `destroy` and `release` **in practice**. Consider such code:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, conn)
{
  if (err)
    throw err;

  console.log("Connected");
  conn.release();
});
```

This will hang forever. If I switch `release` to `destroy` the program terminates. The example from the project page has such piece of code:

```
connection.release();
// Don't use the connection here, it has been returned to the pool.
```

So both are terminating-like only `release` is not terminating. My question is -- what is the use of `release` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it appears, non-terminating state is intentional to keep the pool alive, and "cycle" the connections. For some batch job it is not that important. Here is the answer by sidorares: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1486

Answer (score 3):

Before you continue, keep in mind that I never used this before and I just read the documentation and I think the difference is explained in the documentation by this:

> Connections are lazily created by the pool. If you configure the pool to allow up to 100 connections, but only ever use 5 simultaneously, only 5 connections will be made. Connections are also cycled round-robin style, with connections being taken from the top of the pool and returning to the bottom.

Whereas destroy is this

> This will cause an immediate termination of the underlying socket. Additionally destroy() guarantees that no more events or callbacks will be triggered for the connection.

So I thought of the the connection as like an object instance of the underlying "main" connection pool object. You create connection and you can execute queries out of it. When you release a connection, that connection object is emptied. This is not the main connection referred as the "pool".

When you use release, software is still connected to the underlying database. When you use destroy, software is no longer connected to the database.

Lets say I have 5 connection instances and queries are follows

```
conn1 => select statement that takes 5 mins. 
conn2 => execute a procedure that takes 30 mins. 
conn3 => delete stuff under a min 
conn4 => nothing 
conn5 => nothing
```

In the documentation, it is clear that pool queues the connections and if I execute the connection statements in the same order as above, conn 3 will execute after 5 + 30 mins. What if during the second connection execution, user hits cancel? Then I would release that specific connection which is conn2 but I am still connected to the db so the conn3 can start executing.

Think of it as in javascript you can add stuff to the object's prototype, and you are encouraged to, and you can delete whatever you added. The original object still remains and even if you delete stuff on the prototype, original object is not destroyed.

Comment: Thank you, your example is not correct though, because if you have 5 connections, instead of one, then they are independent of each other, so `conn3` can be used no matter what you do with `conn2`. But you gave me idea -- maybe `release` is supposed to be called "on the side" (user cancels the action...), while `destroy` in the main pipeline to terminate connection. I will try to mimic this...

Comment: I was just making a dumb example hahaha but I think you got my point when you said `destroy` in the main pipeline to terminate connection. `release` : hey stop executing this and go away and `destroy`: all lanes are closed no traffic allowed we shut down everything.